# MySql - find in which partition a row is stored

Tags: mysql, partition

Is there a way to find out in which partition a particular `row` is stored?

I've created a `table` partitioned by `HASH(YEAR(date))` and would like to find out which partition `rows` from a particular `date` are stored.

It looks like it's not possible to obtain this information by running:

`set @partition_name=HASH(YEAR(date))`

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do this:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE date = '2017-07-20'
```

You will get the following information about the rows in some_table having today's date: 
***id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra***

You can also check the MySQL documentation for this from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-info.html)

Answer (score 1):

This question's old now, but it was the one that came up when I searched.

I think this should work.

MySql calculates the modulus of the value you use as the hash to the number of partitions for your table, as described in [their docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-hash.html#:%7E:text=When%20PARTITION%20BY%20HASH%20is%20used).

For example, if your table is called *sales* and has 50 partitions, a row with the date 2017-07-20 will live in the partition with this name:

```
select partition_name from information_schema.partitions 
where table_name = 'sales' 
and partition_ordinal_position = 1+ abs(mod(year('2017-07-20'), 50));
```